# Can I use fft of Matlab in this case?

Tags: fourier-analysis, matlab

fft is a function for Fast Fourier transform. In Matlab help document, Y=fft(x), $\rightarrow$ $X(k)=\sum\limits_{j=1}^Nx(j)w_N^{(j-1)(k-1)}$ where $w_N=e^{(-2\pi i/N)}$ and $N$ is the length of $x$.

In my case x is a function of $\theta$ having periods $2\pi$.So $w_N$ should be $e^{(-2\pi i/2\pi)}$,not the length of x.

Thus, I should write a code for my case. I cannot use Matlab fft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFT is an algorithm for taking [**discrete** Fourier transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), which is the transform of a function defined on a finite set: $0,1,\dots,N-1$. The formula for its coefficients involves summation.

If you have something of period $2\pi$, you are probably thinking of [Fourier series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series). The formula for its coefficients involves integration, which can be implemented numerically in various ways, including Matlab's built-in [integral](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) routine.